# Help me to cutting circle in LaTeX

Tags: circles

[image: Can Help me make this in latex]

Can someone help me to make this in latex.

Comment: Before just dropping this question here... look around our site and see how others ask questions. In particular, this question is lacking a "show of effort". There are many packages you can use to create this image, but laying a foundation for that - you providing a minimal example showing some work towards a solution - would be welcomed.

Comment: This example in the Tikz Gallery will get you started.  http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/venn-diagram/

Comment: im not understanding how to make coordinats like this.. anyway thank u

Answer (score 4):

You can first fill circle A,B and C then draw circumferences

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,tikz]{standalone}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(135:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(135:4cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

%fill circles and add nodes A,B,C
\path[fill=green]\firstcircle node{C};
\path[fill=red]  \secondcircle node{B};
\path[fill=blue] \thirdcircle node{A};

%draw circles
\draw \firstcircle;
\draw \secondcircle;
\draw \thirdcircle;

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tikz` package, like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=green] (3,1) circle [radius=1] node{$C$};
\draw [fill=red] (2,2) circle [radius=1] node{$B$};
\draw [fill=blue] (1,3) circle [radius=1] node{$A$};

\draw (3,1) circle [radius=1];
\draw (2,2) circle [radius=1];
\draw (1,3) circle [radius=1];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The first three orders in the `tikzpicture` environment mean the following: draw, and then fill it with a color, in point (x,y) a circle of radius z, and write down letter X in math mode. Note the order in which I fill the circles: green, then red, then blue, to match the picture you post.

The next three lines of code say: draw in point (x,y) a circle of radius z. If you don't put these codelines, then the `fill` option of the three previous lines "erase" the boundary lines.

[image: circles without boundary lines] [image: circles with boundary lines]

Lastly, you can play with the length of the circles' radii and the centers themselves to match your exact figure.